# Why I get "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: " while using Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-collection

I want to query few tables and return as JSON output for my mobile app.

```
public function index(){
    $data['filters'] = Filters::orderBy('id','asc')->where('ftype', 'r')->get();

    $data['categories'] = Category::where('status','=','A')
    ->where('parent_id',0)
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->get();

    $data['requests'] = URequest::with('user.profile')
        ->whereIn ('requests.status', ['A','B'])
        ->orderBy('requests.created_at','desc')
        ->get();

    $data['today'] = new Carbon(date("Y-m-d"));

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

When I run the above code on Postman, I get this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 265962 of the JSON data.

If I check the raw-data then it shows the data but also, some HTML error like 
"

## Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

".

This code should work but as a work around, I also tried: `$data = array()` at the beginning but it's not working either.

Could anybody please advise what I'm missing here?

Comment: it should work. I can't see a specific error. Please try to debug. before you return your response try dd($data);
maybe you are missing a use statement or something else...

Comment: @jCoders: no - that's not the issue.

Comment: can you `dd($data)` and post the output here.

Comment: Sounds like an escaping issue. Check if `response()->json(...);` generates a valid json string.

Comment: @BramVerstraten It still gives error even if I do: return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => "test data"
        ]);

Comment: I get this:  {"success":true,"data":"test data"}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>                body { background-color: #fff; color: #222; margin: 0; }
                .container { margin: 30px; max-width: 600px; }
                h1 { color: #dc3545; font-size: 24px; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
                        <div class="container">
                    <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: @danish-khan-I When I do: dd($data['requests']) , It gives Collection {#346 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => UserRequest {#342 ▶}
    1 => UserRequest {#339 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: Try converting your data to array before parsing to json using toArray() method after ->get().

Comment: If you check, $data is already an array. Do we still need to do toArray() ?

Comment: @chuck that doesn't help please edit your post and upload the whole dd result or post it somewhere else so we can have a look.

Comment: @danish-khan-I dd($data) gives just fine result. Collection {#346 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => UserRequest {#342 ▼
      #table: "requests"
      #fillable: array:22 [▶]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:25 [▶]
      #original: array:25 [▶]
..      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => UserRequest {#339 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: I've pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/Z9yprc1w

Comment: What does your logs say about the error? Maybe enable APP_DEBUG in your env file and post what are the whoops page's error details

Comment: Thanks @mdexp, I did turn on APP_DEBUG and found a solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code portion that I removed from the index.php that I had added to avoid jwt authentication.

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: cache-control, content-type, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, authorization");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,FILES");
```

This snippet was causing this error:

> "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/xx/public/live/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:1286)"

and hence, was throwing that extra html to the browser: